# Problems with latex script compiling

Tags: compiling

everyone!I'm going to submit thesis on the conference, but I've faced with some problems when compiling the thesis template. Could you, please help me to deal with  it? Here goes code (I'm sorry, it's in russian)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts}
\textwidth=110mm
\textheight=168mm

\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Гаусс К.\,Ф. Название тезисов}

\begin{center}
\bf Название тезисов \\
К.\,Ф.~Гаусс (Город, Страна)\\
your@email.com\\
\end{center}


Объем тезисов не должен превышать 2 стр.

Файл должен компилироваться с помощью LaTeX без ошибок и переполнений.

Имя файла должно содержать фамилию и инициалы автора латинскими буквами (напр., "GaussCF.tex").

Используйте, по возможности, самые простые команды, шрифты, способы оформления. Поскольку все присланные файлы будут собираться в один, то не следует переопределять команды и вводить свои макросы, а также использовать автоматическую нумерацию формул, библиографии, теорем и пр.

Пример оформления определений и утверждений типа теорем, лемм:


\smallskip
\textbf{Теорема~1.} {\it Формулировка теоремы}

Пример оформления литературы:

\smallskip
{\small {\bf{Л и т е р а т у р а}} \nopagebreak

1. \textit{Гаусс К.\,Ф.}  Название статьи. Название журнала. 1977. Том.~57, №.~8, стр.~31--97.

2. \textit{Гаусс К.\,Ф.} Название монографии.  Издательство. 1988.

\end{document}
```

Comment: if you highlight the code and use the `{}` button it is formatted as code (I did it this time:-)

Comment: what error message do you get?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If I delete the line

```
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
```

Then your document runs without error, and produces the above.

With the code as posted you get a spurious error about missing `$` if the file is encoded in UTF-8 but wrongly declared as cp1251.  Unfortunately I can not tell what encoding your original file was in as code is always converted to UTF-8 as it is posted to this site.